# What are the best strategies for handling JSON data in Android?

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I'm trying to figure out the best strategy for data caching in Android, particularly in view of using the data binding library.

The Android documentation really seems to put a lot of emphasis on using the built-in SQLite database and to access this with the help of content providers. However, assuming that my app retrieves data in JSON format from a REST API, using this strategy would entail the following:

```
Make HTTP request --> Parse JSON --> Insert results into DB 
--> Call content provider --> Build model from cursor --> Bind to view
```

Not only does this seem like a very roundabout way of doing something relatively simple, but assuming all this happens when the user first opens the app the result would be lots and lots of waiting before anything useful appears on the screen.

To speed things up I may then decide to create my model earlier and let the caching take place in a separate thread, like this:

```
Make HTTP request --> Build model from JSON --> Bind to view
                  -->(NEW THREAD) --> Insert results into DB
```

Once the data is cached, the next time the user opens the app the following would take place:

```
Call content provider --> Build model from cursor --> Bind to view
```

But of course this would add even more complexity, for example forcing me to maintain code to build the model from two sources: JSON and the cursors returned by the content provider.

Given the above I am even more tempted to do away with the SQLite/ContentProvider model and instead do the following:

```
Make HTTP request --> Build Model and Store JSON to file --> Bind to view
```

But while this would greatly reduce boilerplate, parsing (plenty of libraries available for JSON parsing) and overall complexity it would also mean I cannot take advantage of content providers nor of SQLite's functionality.

So the question is, which model should I follow? Are there situations in which one is better than the other? Or are there better ways of handling this process that I am not aware of?

Comment: I know this does not really answer your question, but could it be an alternative for you to deliver the data in a preloaded SQLite DB? In that case I suggest you check out this little tutorial: http://www.6020peaks.com/2015/03/how-to-ship-an-android-app-with-preloaded-data/

Comment: Probably not. My data changes very frequently so it's pretty useless unless it's fresh off the API.

Comment: Ok. In that case I suggest to check out the code of the Google IO app. I remember they solved the same issue you have for retrieving data for their different events: https://github.com/google/iosched

You might want to start here: https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/master/updater/src/main/java/com/google/iosched/input/fetcher

Comment: More info about the JSON part here: https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/doc/SYNC.md

Comment: @spacitron how did you solve this problem?

Comment: @RamanSB In the end I went with third party solutions. I'm using Realm/RXJava so I completely did away with the complexity of Android's API's.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to your problem could be the one used in the [Google IO app](https://github.com/google/iosched). They parse JSON available on a remote server and display that content directly. In order to avoid empty screens they use a bootstrap json file containing an image of the data available on the server. All this info is available [here](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/doc/SYNC.md). More concretely:

> Bootstrap data
> When the user runs the app for the first time, they expect to see data. However, if we relied only on the sync mechanism to bring data into the app, a first-time user would stare at a blank screen while waiting for a sync to happen, and this would be a bad user experience.
>
> This is why IOSched ships with preloaded "bootstrap data", which is essentially a preloaded offline snapshot of the JSON data. This data is parsed by the app and saved to the database on first execution.
>
> You can find this file in res/raw/bootstrap.json. It is simply a text file with a combined snapshot of the JSON files on the server.

Comment: That's cool but not a solution to my overall problem. What I'm really asking here is how do I go from raw JSON data to a meaningful UI display without introducing mountains of boilerplate and complexity?